# WinBUGS/OpenBUGS Gamma distribution parameters

Tags: bugs

According to the WinBUGS manual the gamma distribution is defined by:

`dgamma(r,mu)`

However, what is `r`? Is it the shape, scale or rate parameter? I'm pretty new to statistics and googling didn't really help. Above that in most explanations I've found `r`is usually not mentioned. It's either k, `theta`, `beta` or `alpha`.

Comment: I'd guess `r` is the shape & `mu` is the mean. Should be documented somewhere, as there's no one 'right' way to parametrize a distribution. You could simulate some values to check. In JAGS it's shape then rate.

Comment: Some details given in this excellent answer on the differences between BUGS and R distribution syntax... http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/5564/13267

Comment: Wow, then it's completely different from what I thought. I thought mu was the mean since gamma distributions can also be defined by the mean.

Comment: The density function *is* given in the [WinBUGS user manual](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/winbugs/manual14.pdf).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software documentation, not Statistics.

Comment: Yes, being a beginner in statistics, I still have a habit of just ignoring formulas a lot. Thanks for pointing me to it. I didn't even notice the density function. I'll try to reword the question.